# Long PHP FORMs are cut off when they are submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, post

I have one page with a large form inside: Table with more than 2000 vars.

I know about max_input_vars and in my php.ini I set:

```
max_input_vars = 3000
```

But the problem is the same.

If I make the count, only 1000 variables are returned.

When I am using

```
var_dump(ini_get('max_input_vars'));
```

The result is 3000:

Do you know where I can be wrong?

I am using symfony, is tehre any difference?

Comment: What about max_post_size?

Comment: You mean post_max_size ? It is set to 8MB.

Comment: ah yes, always get the words mixed. If the form was submitted by GET, there would be a reason for this, but you're doing it via POST. Anywhere you're putting these values to a COOKIE / reading them from a COOKIE? On different approach, maybe you've got something like this going on - `variable[]=5&variable[]=6&variable=7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed with the bagonyi's help.

In fact, I was using suhoin and I had to set in my php.ini:

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000
```

That resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you exceed `max_input_vars` you would get a PHP Warning: Input variables exceeded 1000 so it must be related to something else.

First you need to make sure that the browser is sending all the data. You can do some debugging via browser console, eg. serialize the form $('#form').serialize() and inspect it or count the number of inputs within the form, or post the values and inspect the HTTP message; most probably you will find that the browser is not sending the whole form for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked the post in the Firebug NET visualizer and I am submitting everything.

Comment: The wierd thing is that I am getting exactly 1000 variables back.

Comment: Anything in php error log? And is it the same if you try with a different browser? Preferably in incognito mode where all the add-ons are disabled. To make sure that symfony is not the one causing this behaviour you could edit app_dev.php for example and add die(var_dump($_POST)); to the first line

Comment: I am checking the /var/log/nginx/myproject_error.log and there is nothing. Tryed with chrome and firefox, same issue. I added the die on app_dev.php and the same result, only one part of the form is posted with exactly 1000 vars.

Comment: @Milos, can you please put the output of the data you're sending to the server on pastebin, or such?

Comment: It is getting more likely that the problem is with `max_input_vars`, however it is strange that you don't get any warnings. Double check that you edited the right php.ini, you restarted the web server, you are checking the right error log, etc. You could also write a small perl/ruby/node script that dumps the incoming post parameters. However not sure if those interpreters are having the same limit mechanism as php or not.. Might worth a try.

Comment: Problem fixed. In faact, I also installed suhoin and he is setting the vars limit to 1000. I simply added: `[suhosin] suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000 suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, +1 for you